# Detect table to view materialization change in CI

Tags: dbt

Is there an easy way to detect a change in materialization in CI, to avoid a dbt run failure with  the error

```
Compilation Error in model stores_stores
(models/marts/core/blah.sql)   Trying to create view
`blah`.`dbt`.`blah`, but it currently exists as a
table. Either drop `blah`.`dbt`.`blah` manually,
or run dbt with `--full-refresh` and dbt will drop it for you.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, however it's not particularly "easy".

What you can do is leverage the [artifacts that dbt generates](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-artifacts/).

- `manifest.json`: produced by `compile`, `run`, `test`, `docs generate`, `ls`
- `run_results.json`: produced by `run`, `test`, `seed`, `snapshot`, `docs generate`
- `catalog.json`: produced by `docs generate`

The information for materialisation change can be found in both the `run_results` and the `manifest`. However, in your context of adding a check to the CI in order to fail early, you want to be notified before getting an error from a `dbt run`. So you could actually generate the `manifest.json` with `dbt compile`.

In the `nodes` key of the manifest, each node will have a `config.materialized` key that you can look at. You can parse that with the command line or with python and store the result to a JSON file which holds the materialisation information of each model. That file can be checked-in into your code for example.

```sh
cat target/manifest.json | jq '.nodes | to_entries | map({node: .key, materialized: .value.config.materialized})' > old_state.json
```

Then after you've made a change to your dbt code, you need to run

```sh
dbt compile  # generates new manifest.json
cat target/manifest.json | jq '.nodes | to_entries | map({node: .key, materialized: .value.config.materialized})' > new_state.json
```

You can then compare two states with e.g. `diff` in the command line. I'll put an example output here:

```sh
$ diff old_state.json new_state.json
12c12
<     "materialized": "table"
---
>     "materialized": "view"
```

As I said, this is not "easy" per say, but I hope my answer gave you some ideas on how to proceed to get what you want. If you're interested in more details, you can check [my blog post on the topic](https://guitton.co/posts/dbt-artifacts/).